# Using command line for operating on files and folders mounted on windows partition

Tags: mount, filesystem

I have a dual boot system with win8 and Ubuntu saucy. Can I use the command line to copy/move/edit/delete files and folders located on the windows partition? How do I set the path to that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Path would be the Mountpoint of your Windows-Partition.

You could also modify /etc/fstab to define the Mountpoint.
You might want to check this Wiki-Page for fstab:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab

Example:

1. Create a Folder called "Win8Partition" in your Home-Directory
2. Open fstab with your preferred Text-Editor, e.g. nano.

   sudo nano /etc/fstab
3. Add the Partition at the end of fstab, e.g.

   /dev/sdxY/   /home/yourusername/Win8Partition   ntfs   rw 0 0

(Where "/dev/sdxY/" is the Partition, in my case it's "/dev/sda3")
After that save the Changes made to fstab and exit nano. Your Windows-Partition will be
mounted to the Folder "Win8Partition" after a Reboot and you should be able to browse and modify Files from there.

Sorry for my broken english. Feel free to edit :-)